# Android crash analytics, logging, exception tracking, usage, etc. bewildering array of options

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center, crashlytics-android, bugsnag, instabug

I want to to use a service for crash reporting and I see that there are a few options [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/products/crashlytics), [Instabug](https://instabug.com/), [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/), [Bugfender](https://bugfender.com/), [Splunk Mint](https://mint.splunk.com/), [Visual Studio App Center](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/app-center/), etc.

1. I am cost constrained, so I don't want to spend a lot particularly at this early stage.
2. I want more than just crash information, I want to be able to log exceptions and things which don't crash the app but impact the user experience.
3. Can additional logging be added?
4. Not essential, but I would like to see how users are using my app as well.

I see Crashlytics is free but it even address items 2, 3, and 4? Do people use multiple tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Crashlytics does the crash collection part very well, but I don't think it does the rest. It's free, although there are the privacy implications of using a Google service.
- Bugfender does all of the functions you mentioned: it collects crashes/exceptions and other errors that do not crash your application (called "issues"). Besides exceptions, you can collect application logs and navigation. It has a free plan that might be enough for your purposes, especially if you mention you're early stage.
- Splunk is "enterprise". They might have a free plan, but they're not advertising it. I think it does most of what you are looking for, as well.

I do not know in detail the rest of the tools you mentioned, so I prefer to keep my opinion to myself.

Disclosure: my answer might be biased, I'm co-founder of Bugfender.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. App Center seems to do the same piece as Crashlytics, and is free, but also feeds data to Application Insights, which is not. It did help me get started. Bugfender seems to be purpose built for this. I happen to have a monthly Azure allowance, so I went with App Center and Application Insights to get started.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer by @gimix, Instabug Crash-Reporting does all this AFAIK. It's mentioned on the [website](https://instabug.com/product/crash-reporting).

[image: A screenshot]